# Утечка памяти в WPF приложении

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6

Имею приложение на WPF. Есть анимация, шрифты, отрисовка BitmapSource картинок (думал дело в них, но по анализу памяти как-то не наткнулся на них).

DotMemory показывает рост неуправляемой памяти. Сделал дамп, проанализировал через DebugDiag2 - показывает высокую вероятность утечки в D3DCompiler_47_cor3.
Что это может быть?

```
Function details

Function   D3DCompiler_47_cor3!DebugSetMute+15d93c 
Source Line    
Allocation type   Heap allocation(s) 
Heap handle   0x00000000`00000000 
Allocation Count   2234704 allocation(s) 
Allocation Size   387,34 MBytes 
Leak Probability   94% 


Call stack sample 1

Address   0x0039fffe`fffe0300 
Allocation Time   00:05:00 since tracking started 
Allocation Size   448 Bytes 
   

LeakTrack+20b07       
D3DCompiler_47_cor3!DebugSetMute+15d93c       
D3DCompiler_47_cor3!DebugSetMute+14e15f       
D3DCompiler_47_cor3!DebugSetMute+648       
D3DCompiler_47_cor3!DebugSetMute+6d8       
D3DCompiler_47_cor3!DebugSetMute+2d2fe       
D3DCompiler_47_cor3!DebugSetMute+9ab1a       
D3DCompiler_47_cor3!DebugSetMute+9d853       
D3DCompiler_47_cor3!D3DWriteBlobToFile+474       
D3DCompiler_47_cor3!D3DWriteBlobToFile+8d8       
D3DCompiler_47_cor3!D3DWriteBlobToFile+19d1       
D3DCompiler_47_cor3!D3DCompile2+e3       
D3DCompiler_47_cor3!D3DCompile+6c       
wpfgfx_cor3!RenderOptions_IsSoftwareRenderingForcedForProcess+5a25e       
wpfgfx_cor3!RenderOptions_IsSoftwareRenderingForcedForProcess+56d70       
wpfgfx_cor3!RenderOptions_IsSoftwareRenderingForcedForProcess+5bb8d       
wpfgfx_cor3!MILAddRef+507c       
wpfgfx_cor3!MILAddRef+185e4       
wpfgfx_cor3!MILAddRef+f8b6       
wpfgfx_cor3!MILAddRef+7140       
wpfgfx_cor3!MILAddRef+7058       
wpfgfx_cor3!MILAddRef+8ef7       
wpfgfx_cor3!MILRelease+1693d       
wpfgfx_cor3!MILAddRef+1c5e5       
wpfgfx_cor3!MilContent_DetachFromHwnd+503ac       
wpfgfx_cor3!MilContent_DetachFromHwnd+4f050       
wpfgfx_cor3!MilContent_DetachFromHwnd+52710       
wpfgfx_cor3!MilContent_DetachFromHwnd+5d3c5       
wpfgfx_cor3!MilContent_DetachFromHwnd+51493       
wpfgfx_cor3!MilContent_DetachFromHwnd+53aab       
wpfgfx_cor3!MilContent_DetachFromHwnd+56946       
wpfgfx_cor3!MilContent_DetachFromHwnd+54f1f
```

Причем первые 2 часа все шло нормально. Потом начался рост. В программе ничего не менялось.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `D3DCompiler` - это из пакета `DirectX`, разбирайтесь с ним. Обновления, другие драйвера видео попробовать и т.д.

Comment: Версия дотнета какая?

Comment: @aepot  версия net 6.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал создать воспроизводимый пример (MRE) и зарепортить это на GitHub WPF

Comment: @aepot это достаточно сложно. Но надо пробовать. Заменил версию D3DCompiler 10.0.22621.1778 (net  6.0.25) на версию 10.0.19041.685 (net 6.0.1) - на первый взгляд проблема ушла. Тестирую.

Comment: можно ради эксперимента на .NET 8 перескочить

Comment: Обновил драйвер видеокарты - стало лучше. Отключил аппаратный рендеринг в WPF- стало идеально. Проблема где-то в драйвере что ли... хм.